# Add Class to Label of Defaulted Checked Checkbox and Radio

Tags: jquery, css, forms

I've found a lot of example of this, but none with exactly what I'm trying to do in one nugget. I need to change the label (the label must be wrapped around the input for my fancy inputs) of the checkbox or radio depending if the checkbox or radio is "checked." Some of these inputs will be checked upon arriving at the form, so the class needs to show upon arrival if checked.

It's working now for checkboxes, but how do I add radio buttons into the mix without breaking it? Appreciate the help!

Here's my HTML/CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.c_on {color: #F0F;}
.r_on {color: #0F0;}
</style>

<fieldset class="checkboxes">

    <label for="chk1"><input type="checkbox" id="chk1" />chk1</label><br />
    <label for="chk2"><input type="checkbox" id="chk2" checked="checked" />chk2</label>

</fieldset>

<fieldset class="radios">

    <label for="rdo1"><input type="radio" name="group1" id="rdo1" />rdo1</label><br />
    <label for="rdo2"><input type="radio" name="group1" id="rdo2" checked="checked" />rdo2</label>

</fieldset>
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Turn checkbox class on */
    var checkOn = 'c_on'

    function toggleLabelClass(input){
        var $input = $(input);
        if ($input.is('[type="checkbox"]:checked')){
            $input.parent('label').addClass(checkOn);
        }else{
            $input.parent('label').removeClass(checkOn)
        }
    }
    $(function() {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
            toggleLabelClass(this);
            $(this).click(function(evt){
                toggleLabelClass(evt.target);
            });
        });
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P2n2V/

Comment: Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P2n2V/

Comment: Please end all of your statements with `;`. And I'm wondering, have you even tried to make it work with `radio`s?

Comment: Thank you, I'm still new to jQuery and this is an example I found. I tried to repeat what was done for checkboxes, but I think there's a conflict with the variables. I also want it to be in the correct syntax, so I'm not repeating functions. Trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work :

```
$(function() {
    var inputOn = 'c_on',
        radioOn = 'r_on',
        elms=$('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]');

    function setLabelClass() {
        elms.each(function(i,e) {
            $(e).parent('label')[e.checked?'addClass':'removeClass']($(e).is(':radio')?radioOn:inputOn);
        });
    }

    elms.on('change', setLabelClass);
    setLabelClass();
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qdM2T/)

Comment: @mezzerpezzer - It seems to work just fine for me, what exactly does'nt work ??

Comment: I see it's working in the fiddle, but when I put it in my file it doesn't work. Did I forget something??

http://pixelfarmers.com/beta/checkbox.html

Comment: I still can't find the difference between my file and fiddle, but I went in and got the fiddle HTML file and it's working. When I replace the jQuery from the fiddle html file into my file all is good. Thanks for your help with this! Much appreciate for my first question in stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add radio inputs to the `each()` loop and make some changes to the `toggleLabelClass()` function. Is this is what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/zjc9e/

I am not sure what do you mean by not breaking the mix. Are there any parts of the code you do not want to change?

Comment: Thank YOU!! That worked! One thing though...when you click onto another radio how do you turn the class off on the deselected radio? The radio keeps the class even though it's no longer checked.